# Trying to have my settings screen link to the Log in/Sign Up screen after clicking on the name, why do I keep getting 'undefined is not a function'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, screen, stack-navigator

I want to do a simple task which is go from one screen to another but no matter what i do it won't work. I've installed both the react-navigation/stack and react-navigation/native-stack and neither work with what i have, is it because Tabs?

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Tabs from './navigation/tabs';
import "react-native-url-polyfill/auto"
import LogInSignUp from './SettingsScreen/LogInSignUp';


const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" options={{title: "Welcome"}} component={Tabs} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Tabs} />
            <Stack.Screen name = "LogInSignUp" component={LogInSignUp}/>
          </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;

import { Text, StyleSheet, View, Button, } from "react-native";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";


const Settings = (navigation) => {
    return (
      <View style = {styles.container}>
        <Button title = "LogIn/SignUp" onPress={() => navigation.navigate("LogInSignUp")}></Button>
      </View>
      
    );
  }

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    
  })

export default Settings

import React from 'react'
import { StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

const LogInSignUp = (navigation) => {
  return (
    <div>LogInSignUp</div>
  )
}

export default LogInSignUp
```

I tried to find tutorials explaining the problem and all of their code looks like mine with just switched out names to my .js files and nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this hook

const navigation = useNavigation();

```
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';

const Settings = () => {
const navigation = useNavigation();
    return (
      <View style = {styles.container}>
        <Button title = "LogIn/SignUp" onPress={() => navigation.navigate("LogInSignUp")}></Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not destructuring your props. You're receiving the props as `navigation`. In you're case you should use `navigation.navigation.navigate`.

This should resolve the issue

```js
const Settings = ({ navigation }) => {
  // ...
};
```